# Matrix substitution

Tags: matrix, replacement

I'm newbie in Mathematica and would like to ask one simple question.

Let's say I have matrix with some elements == -1

```
mm = ConstantArray[0, {10, 10}]; 
mm[[4, 4]] = -1; 
mm[[7, 7]] = -1; 
...
```

Now I want to find all occurrences of -1 and set all neighbor cells around them  to some values.

```
pos = Position[mm, -1] (* Positions are kept here *)
```

Now I want to surround these found positions by some values :

```
r1 = {{a1, a2, a3}, {a4, a5, a6}, {a7, a8, a9}};
r2 = {{b1, b2, b3}, {b4, b5, b6}, {b7, b8, b9}};
....
rr = {r1, r2, ....};
```

Only way I could make to work is following cycle :

```
For[i = 1, i <= Length[pos], i++,
  mm[[(pos[[i,1]]-1);;(pos[[i,1]]+1), (pos[[i,2]]-1);;(pos[[i,2]]+1)]] = rr[[i]];
]
```

But it looks really ugly and I suspect would be more slow if I need to do it for bigger number of positions.

Could anyone point me to solution in more functional style ? I played a bit with ReplacePart but couldn't get it working.

Comment: What if `-1` is on edge?

Comment: Or a corner? And what if neighbors from respective -1 elements overlap? Which "neighbors" win.

Comment: Easy but not very efficient: Use `Nearest[]`

Comment: Guys, thanks for the comments, that's not some 'real' piece of code - I just need an idea how to do something  very close to what I showed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following assumes that your replacements are 3x3 matrices but it is easy to generalize. I'm not sure if you need. It will take care of `-1` on edges.

```
replace[mm_, reps_] := Module[{m = ArrayPad[mm, 1], pos = Position[mm, -1]},
  MapThread[
   (m[[#[[1]] ;; #[[1]] + 2, #[[2]] ;; #[[2]] + 2]] = #2) &,
   {pos, reps}];
  ArrayPad[m, -1]]

mm = ConstantArray[0, {10, 10}];
mm[[1, 1]] = -1;
mm[[7, 7]] = -1;
replace[mm, rr] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Nice and clean. +1

Comment: @rasher What tests? p.s. there is `fp` outside of scope in your module.

Comment: never mind re: blow-up, had junk in symbols from testing OP... DOH

Comment: @rasher oh, ok :)

Comment: Excellent, it's exactly what I need ! Edges and corners are not being considered here bcouse it's not real code.